# applying properties depending on the condition result

Tags: javascript

```js
var condition = 1 == 1;
if (condition) {
  document.getElementById('result').classList.add('success');
} else {
  document.getElementById('result').classList.remove('success');
}
```

```css
.success:after {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  content: "Success";
}

span:after {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  content: "Failed";
}
```

```html
<span id="result" data-result=""></span>
```

i want to manipulate the property of `.add` and `.remove` depending on the condition above applying something like this

```
document.getElementById('result').classList.(condition ? add('success') : remove('success'));
```

can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and call the function with the wanted string.

```js
var condition = 1 == 1;

document
    .getElementById('result')
    .classList[condition ? 'add' : 'remove']('success');
```

```css
.success:after { background: green; color: white; content: "Success"; }
span:after { background: red; color: white; content: "Failed"; }
```

```html
<span id="result" data-result=""></span>
```